# App doesn't run on simulator - Parse sample code Anypic

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, parse-platform

For a long time now I've been trying to get the Parse sample code of Anypic to run — no success.
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic

First I had trouble compiling and realized I needed to downgrade to xcode 5.0. Now it compiled but when I run it the simulator opens and shows nothing. No app is installed. When I try my other apps it works fine (not the simulator malfunctioning)

Any advice?

Comment: You say it shows nothing? No application launches at all? I found that when I ran the AnyPic examples, I had to create an application on Parse called anypic, download the application keys, and specify them in my initial parse call.          [Parse setApplicationId:@"XXXXXXXX"
                  clientKey:@"XXXXXXXX"]; which is usually called in  your app delegate's - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{} call

Comment: Don't downgrade to Xcode 5.0. You need to use 5.1 to support iOS 7.1.

Comment: The Anypic tutorial has not been updated to work with the latest version of xcode or ios 7, but I still got it to work with only minor tweaks. Post your errors, and it will be easier to help you.